# AngularJS: unknown provider until after page loads?

Tags: angularjs

So this is really weird, maybe it has a simple answer I'm missing. The following code gives an unknown provider error:

```
var foo = angular.module('foo', [ 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngCookies' ]);

foo.factory('fooApi', function ($scope, $http) {
    var url = '/api/';

    var factory = {};

    factory.action = function (fields) {
        fields.userid = $scope.userid;
        fields.token = $scope.token;

        console.log(JSON.stringify(fields));

        return $http.post(url, { data: fields });
    };

    return factory;
})
.controller('loginController', function ($scope, fooApi) {
    // do stuff

});
```

It's all loading together in the same file, and I'd think the factory being first would resolve and the injector would be able to find it when referenced below. But it gives an unknown provider error.

However, if I comment out the controller and wait for the page to load and then do the exact same controller declaration in the Chrome JS console it works fine.

Anyone run into this before and know how to deal with it? I haven't been able to find this same exact issue anywhere.

Comment: Can you try: `foo.facotry(); foo.controller()`.  Basically without chaining them.  Also is kind of strange to see a `$scope` injected into a factory.  I'm not sure that will work (never tried).  Typically you'd pass in the scope or the two fields (userid, token) to the function.

Comment: Can you show how your `.html` is loading all of your javascript files? I'm wondering if one of your app's dependencies aren't loaded yet...

Comment: You can't inject `$scope` in a factory. Should give you `Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- fooApi`. If you comment out the controller you will not get the error since the factory will not be initiated until someone asks for it the first time.

Comment: Pulling $scope out of the factory fixed it. Thanks guys.

Comment: @tasseKATT, you should consider posting your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like @tasseKATT said, you can not inject `$scope` into a service, particularly a `factory`. Maybe your confusion is because `$scope` can be injected in controllers, so you tried to injected into a `factory`.

An interesting thing is that the `$scope` that you see being injected into controllers is not a service - like the rest of the injectable stuff -, but is a Scope object.

The main purpose of `$scope` is a king of glue between views and controllers, it doesn't make much sense to pass a `$scope` into a service.

The services only have access to the `$rootScope` service.

If you need to pass the `$scope` of a specific controller to a service always you can pass it like parameter of a function in the service. This approach is not recommended because starting to break the SoC and the single responsibility principle, but maybe could fit you.

Good luck :-)